# C++ AES Encryption Class

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need AES encryption for my C++ project. But i don't have the time to study the more popular and complex c++ cryptography libraries. Do you know of any ready made, open source C++ class that implements AES(Rijndael)?

something that provides something like

```
void makekey(....);
string encrypt(string data); //takes plain text, returns encrypted text
string decrypt(string data); //takes encrypted text, returns plain text
```

I have already seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1380/A-C-Implementation-of-the-Rijndael-Encryption-Decr) implementation of AES and am trying to tailor it to my needs but I don't want to reinvent the wheel (and I'm having problems with it). so if you know of such class please let me know.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I recommend [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/), a really easy to use C++ library. It works in different operating systems like Windows and Linux. Don't reinvent the wheel!

Usage samples can be found [here](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).