# Encrypt data block with C/C++, platform independent

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, sha1

Say, if I have a byte array of a various length and a pass-phrase, what is the quickest way to  encrypt it in a platform-independent way?

PS. I can make a SHA1 digest on the pass-phrase but how do I apply it to the byte array -- doing a simple repeated XOR makes it too obvious.

PS2. Sorry, crypto guys, if I"m asking too obvious stuff...

Comment: Do not use SHA1 or XOR in any combination unless you know what you're doing. See, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151178/c-aes-encryption-class

Comment: You generally don't encrypt *with* hashes, you *encrypt hashes* (i.e. signatures). You may need to brush up on your crypto.

Comment: No version of any C or C++ specification provides any cryptographic functions in its standard library. Therefore you need a third-party library. [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/) is reasonably standard and [NaCl](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/) looks promising.

Comment: I think the OP meant to hash the pass-phrase to make a key.

Answer (score 2):

A Hash (like sha1) create a one-way result, you cannot decrypt a hash. XORing the data is not secure by any means, don't do that.

If you need to be able to decrypt the data, then I suggest using something like [Twofish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twofish) which uses a symmetric key block cipher and is not restricted by licensing or patents (thus you can find platform independent reference code).